# What are the differences between every-day makeup and Photography Makeup?

Tags: make-up

What are the differences between every-day makeup and Photography makeup? Can you use regular makeup and get a goodlooking shot or are there certain rules? Should the makeup be darker than in real life for a photoshoot, or does it have to have the same intensity? (I see in almost any video that the makeup is VERY dark, but on the final picture it's well balanced and brighter)

I am not asking about the person who applies the makeup. Let it Always be a professional artist. What I would like to understand is

a) what is the difference in the material/tools/colors itself?

b) is there a clear difference between a all-day makeup waring model and a professional makeup wearing model. (for example the professional beeing darker/more intense/smoother/etc..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short...
Cheap makeup uses cheap components.  These may be more allergic or cause issues to the skin either short or long term.  They also have a tendency to use some sort of "acid" base, which is not good for long term use.

Good, all-day makeup likely won't, however, it is not designed with a camera flash in mind.  Some might include titanium dioxide, a common lightener/whitener.  It also is quite reflective, and can ruin flash photography.  Zinc oxide is also often used and is highly reflective.

A high-grade, high-quality makeup for photography can be worn for a long time with a low risk of complications and low reflectivity.  It is also thicker and will sit on top of the skin.  No professional model will risk short or long term skin damage on crappy makeup.

Makeup for HDTV is also different and shares similar characteristics, including the ability to cover/hide pores and very small skin flaws.